# Setting integrator initial condition basing on the signal in Simulink

Tags: matlab, parameters, simulink

I have simple Simulink model and I would like to change the initial condition of integrator based on some signal. This signal can take values 1 or 0 and initial conditions of integrator should be equal to 1.16 or 0.65 respectively.

I tried to set a parameter `x_init` in Model Workspace (and then use it in Integrator block), but I couldn't access it via function. Then I tried to run MATLAB function inside simulink model with `set_param(...)`, but I got error:

```
Function 'set_param' is not supported for code generation. Consider adding coder.extrinsic('set_param') at the top of the function to bypass code generation.
```

This is how the structure of model looks like in Model Explorer. I would like to change the `x` initial condition.
[image: Model Explorer view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a workspace variable as you are doing is the wrong approach.

Change the `Initial Condition Source` property of the integrator to `external`.  This will give the block an additional in port.  The value of the signal fed into this port when the integrator is reset is taken as the initial condition.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is it the same for other blocks such as PIDs?

Comment: Any block that has resettable states, and the ability to specify the initial condition with an external input, will work like this.